# How to increment "char *" inside a function without returning it?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, function-definition

I have something like this (simplified):

```
void count(char *fmt)
{
    while (*fmt != 'i')
    {
        fmt++;
    }
    printf("%c %p\n", *fmt, fmt);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *a = "do something";
    char *format;

    format = a;
    printf("%c %p\n", *format, format);
    count(format);
    printf("%c %p", *format, format);
}
```

Gives:

```
d 0x100003f8b
i 0x100003f94
d 0x100003f8b%
```

Only way to make it work is by doing:

```
char *count(char *fmt)
{
    while (*fmt != 'i')
    {
        fmt++;
    }
    printf("%c %p\n", *fmt, fmt);
    return (fmt);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *a = "do something";
    char *format;

    format = a;
    printf("%c %p\n", *format, format);
    format = count(format);
    printf("%c %p", *format, format);
}
```

But **I really don't want this** since my count function is already returning a value that I need. What can I do to increment format inside the function without returning it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the pointer to the function by reference.
In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. So dereferencing the pointer you will have a direct access to the original object and can change it.

For example

```
void count(char **fmt)
{
    while ( **fmt != 'i')
    {
        ++*fmt;
    }
    printf("%c %p\n", **fmt, *fmt);
}
```

and call the function like

```
count( &format);
```

Comment: Ok this works but I don't really understand what is happening. My brain bugs out when I have to work with multiple '*'. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @MiguelP In your original function the function deals with a copy of the value of the passed pointer. Changing the copy is not reflected on the original pointer. Passing the pointer by reference through a pointer to it you can access a direct access to the original pointer dereferencing the parameter. It is the same as the difference between these two function declarations void f( int x ); and void f( int *px ); The second function is able to change passed to it an object of the type int through a pointer to it px.

Comment: @MiguelP: Dealing with pointers to anything, including any other pointers, is a major aspect of successful C programming, so time to start coming to terms with it.  Do you understand how pass by reference (using pointers) works in general? `void incr(long *x) { ++*x; }`.  Explain to yourself in words why `long y = 5; incr(&y);` results in `y ==6`.  Now repeat that explanation but replace all instances of `long` with `int *`.

Comment: @NateEldredge This is actually very helpful!